# is a member of multiple groups ("Support Files" and "Support Files")

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

my project by flutter and have working well but after I did `pod update` and this issue has appeared with every build

```
Running pod install...                                             33.8s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           52.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2020-10-07 12:44:35.103 xcodebuild[62632:416549] warning:  The file reference for "GoogleMaps.debug.xcconfig" is a member of multiple
    groups ("Support Files" and "Support Files"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be
    preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add
    another reference to the same path.
    2020-10-07 12:44:35.103 xcodebuild[62632:416549] warning:  The file reference for "GoogleMaps.release.xcconfig" is a member of multiple
    groups ("Support Files" and "Support Files"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be
    preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add
    another reference to the same path.
    ** BUILD FAILED **
```

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/xuser/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-1.0.2/ios/Classes/GoogleMapPolylineController.m:20:15:
    error: property 'userData' not found on object of type 'GMSPolyline *'
        _polyline.userData = @[ polylineId ];
                  ^
    1 error generated.
    /Users/xuser/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-1.0.2/ios/Classes/GoogleMapPolygonController.m:20:14:
    error: property 'userData' not found on object of type 'GMSPolygon *'
        _polygon.userData = @[ polygonId ];
                 ^
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
```

I tried every solutions I found but no one worked .

last solutions I did is

i'm working on flutter

```
Flutter 1.22.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision d408d302e2 (8 days ago) • 2020-09-29 11:49:17 -0700
Engine • revision 5babba6c4d
Tools • Dart 2.10.0
```

flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.0, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G2021, locale en-EG)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.7)
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.47.0)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```